# Connection refused to mosquitto service in Raspbian

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, mqtt, gpio

I installed a fresh and clean new raspbian onto a raspberry pi A+ and added the 1.4.2 mosquitto package from mosquitto.org.

With mqtt-gpio-Monitor from https://github.com/sumnerboy12/mqtt-gpio-monitor/issues/3 i try to connect but always get an error saying connection refused.

Mosquitto_sub works without issues and connects correctly.

The mosquitto service is listening on 0.0.0.0:1883 so what could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the issue you link to you are connecting to port 1833 instead of port 1883.